# Angular form submission does not work with BrowserSync

Tags: angularjs, browser-sync

**Setup:**
I have the following form:

```
<div ng-controller="ChatController">
    <form ng-submit="sendTextMessage()">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="msgInput">
    </form>
</div>
```

and the following in ChatController:

```
$scope.sendTextMessage = function() {
    //Do some socket.io to send $scope.msgInput
    $scope.messageInput = '';
}
```

I have loaded the page in two Chrome browsers, which are synced using BrowserSync.

**Expected result:**
The sendTextMessage() function is called in both browsers, no HTTP request is sent to the server, page is not refreshed.

**The problem:**
Everything works as expected in the browser where I'm typing the input (submitting by pressing 'enter'). But the other browser refreshes the page , and now has '/?' appended to the URL. From what I can tell, the other browser just performed the default submit behaviour, and didn't run my sendTextMessage() function.

**What I've done so far:**
Call sendTextMessage($event), and handle it with event.preventDefault(). Made no difference.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Angular, BrowserSync, Chrome, or something else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Enter` and other similar keypress are not synced by `browser-sync` as of now. There are also couple of issues with `ev.stopPropagation` and contenteditable syncing.

My pull request for these fixes haven't been merged yet. But if you'd like you can clone the repo directly - https://github.com/nitinsurana/browser-sync